# Django redirecting NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I am tearing my hair out trying to understand why I am getting `NoReverseMatch` error.

I am trying to get it to add a participant and return to the list of participants on the particular study. I am also trying to get a back button working but I also get a NoReverseMatch error.

Urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.homepage, name='homepage'),
    path('studies/', views.studylist, name='studylist'),
    path('studies/add_study', views.add_study, name='add_study'),
    path('studies/<int:id>', views.study_update, name='study_edit'),
    path('studies/<int:id>/participants', views.participantlist, name='participantlist'),
    path('studies/<int:id>/participants/add_participant', views.add_participant, name='add_participant')]
```

Views

```
def participantlist(request, id):
    participant_list = Participant.objects.filter(study_id=id)
    return render(request, 'databank/participants.html',
        {'participantlist':participant_list, 'study_id':id})

def add_participant(request, id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ParticipantForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            participant_item = form.save(commit=False)
            participant_item.study_id = id
            participant_item.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('participantlist', args=(id,)))
    else:
        form = ParticipantForm()
    return render(request, 'studies/add_participant.html', {'form': form})
```

Template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Study Participant</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Add or Edit Participant</h1>
<p>Please fill in the required information and click save to add a participant</p>
<form method="POST" action=" ">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
{{ form }}
</table>
<br>
  <input type="submit" value="Save">
</br>
</form>
<br />
<form action="{% url 'participantlist' %}">
<input type="submit" value="Back" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

NoReverseMatch

```
Reverse for 'participantlist' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['studies/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/participants$']

Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/studies/1/participants/add_participant

Django Version: 2.1
Python Version: 3.7.0
Installed Applications:
['databank.apps.DatabankConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template 
C:\Projects\mysite\databank\templates\studies\add_participant.html, error at 
line 19
Reverse for 'participantlist' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) 
tried: 
['studies/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/participants$']
9 : <form method="POST" action=" ">
10 :   {% csrf_token %}
11 :   <table>
12 :   {{ form }}
13 :   </table>
14 :     <br>
15 :       <input type="submit" value="Save">
16 :     </br>
17 :   </form>
18 :   <br />
19 :   <form action=" {% url 'participantlist' %} ">
20 :     <input type="submit" value="Back" />
21 :   </form>
22 :   </body>
23 : </html>
24 : 

Traceback:

File "C:\Projects\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" 
in inner
34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Projects\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in 
_get_response
 126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, 
request)

File "C:\Projects\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in 
_get_response
 124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, 
**callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Projects\mysite\databank\views.py" in add_participant
70.     return render(request, 'studies/add_participant.html', {'form': 
form})

File "C:\Projects\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, 
using=using)

File "C:\Projects\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in 
render_to_string
62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "C:\Projects\myvenv\lib\site- 
packages\django\template\backends\django.py" 
in render
61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Projects\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
171.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Projects\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in 
_render
163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Projects\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Projects\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in 
render_annotated
904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Projects\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in 
render
442.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, 
current_app=current_app)

File "C:\Projects\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
90.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, 
**kwargs))

File "C:\Projects\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py" in 
_reverse_with_prefix
  622.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /studies/1/participants/add_participant
Exception Value: Reverse for 'participantlist' with no arguments not found. 1 
pattern(s) tried: ['studies/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/participants$']
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the code that's generating the error? I wouldn't expect `{% url 'participantlist' %}` to cause an error message containing `with arguments '('',)'`, and `reverse('participantlist', args=(id,))` should work because `id` comes from the URL.

Comment: Please add the full error traceback.

Comment: Your url is expecting an int but you are sending a string ("").

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to get the URL for a path that has a variable field (in your path definition you are trying to capture an ID (`path('studies/<int:id>/participants', [...])`), but when you ask for the reverse URL using the path name there is no match because no URL actually exists for that path that does not have an id. So, in other words, **you are telling Django that all participantlist must have an ID in the URL, *but* you are not specifying it when you try to get the ReverseMatch**.

You could tell the Django template engine the parameters for it to find a match with this syntax:

```
{% url 'path_name' keyword_arg=keyword_val %}
```

So your implementation would be:

```
{% url 'participantlist' id=the_id %}
```

Where `the_id` (or any other name you decide, for that matter) is a variable you have to set in your Django render request passing the appropriate ID. I see you may have already passed that variableas the `study_id` but I am not really sure because I do not know which ID stands for what. Anyway, in general I think you are getting the app logic wrong. It seems you are sending the action to add a participant to the URL that is in charge of retreiving a participants list, when it should be for the `add_participant`.

#### Edit

I don't recommend mixing up *adding* and *editing* in your views. Adding should be for an instance that is not yet created and does not have its own ID (in your case, participants have ID as well as the other structure that contains participants, which has a different ID list). In order to add a participant, you go to a form that does not have any pre-set information about the participant you want to add (unless you explicitly decide to), whereas editing should be a different URL map that requests the existing participant's ID in order to edit it (as well as login credentials if you decide to).

Both paths should accept get and post; this you got right. Get renders a form, but listen up: the form's action should be the same as the get's URL; only that when you post the data your view's logic will perceive it and take appropriate measures.

You can optionally separate GET and POST URL when it refers to data editing, but this is not generally encouraged since you may mix it up with the action of getting the data that there already is (and not getting the form to edit the data, which is different).

To clarify this last bit: your `participantlist`<sup>1</sup> path is for getting the participant list, not for editing the data of any participant. If you had a path to get info from just one participant, this could be

```
path('studies/<int:study_id>/participants/<int:participant_id>', views.get_participant, name='get_participant')
```

While the path to edit this participant (with both GET and POST methods) would be:

```
path('studies/<int:study_id>/participants/<int:participant_id>/edit', views.edit_participant, name='edit_participant')
```

---

**Footnotes**

<sup>1</sup> (it's stylistically better if you add an underscore to separate words like `participant_list`)